# Critique: How should I place/format an informative text in a picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, critique, advertising

I am trying to advertise some discounts in Facebook and to do that I have to provide an image that has a small amount of text informing potential customers about the discount I am offering.

I am having trouble deciding where to properly place the text, what size it should be or what color. My goal is to make the text pop so that it is apparent and doesn't blend in with the background image, but at the same time is aesthetically pleasing.

Any tips for a first time designer?

[image: Here is what I have done so far!]

The above image is what I've done so far

[image]

This is the original image

Comment: Please please please don't stretch the image. PLEASE

Comment: Any chance you're able to post the background photo without text and logo? Would be easier for me to diagram on / create a mock-up with.

Comment: In case no one mentioned it... Please don't squish the image. It always looks horrible. :) This would appear to be brainstorming and idea gathering and is generally off-topic.

Comment: Hi Cesar, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: Offtopic. I am picky on the use of the phrase "First time designer". Can you imagine a first time Medic? Grabing a design tool, or making your first advertising does not make someone a designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is proper contrast between text and the background. When you put text on an image, this is always a challenge. It becomes especially challenging when you have a photo like this, where there is no one particular are of dark or lightness overall.

To fix that you need to layer in your own elements to create contrast.

Here's but a couple of examples. One using a block of color, the other using a semi-opaque overlay.

[image]

You could add to this more...perhaps the yellow bar is more of a flag shape, or add a drop shadow to it to make it appear floating.

As a bonus, you can use these blocks of color to better frame the photo and pseudo-crop out the uninteresting parts (in this case, the roof and the huge sidewalk)

But the point is that you are artificially creating a more 'even' background to have a consistent contrast with the foreground type.

Your example is outlining the type. This can work in rare cases, but it usually makes the type that much harder to read, so would avoid using that in most situations.

Answer (score 5):

First of all my suggestion would be to ensure that the aspect ration of the image is maintained. This is one of the most important aspect of making any design aesthetically pleasing.

Secondly, my suggestion would be to create a tab on the side of the image, (As I think you have a narrower image than required.
This tab can be of the color you want and can have the discounts you are offering in BOLD. This will ensure that this is one of the first thing people notice.

Also, the company logo can be moved to top-right corner of the image with/without a polygon as a background.

Answer (score 5):

You have bigger problems than the words.

That picture is anti-advertising.

The guy in the foreground is sitting down. On the job. Potential customers don't want you camped out at their house for half the day.

There's cleaning equipment on the lawn. If you know how hard it is to get a good, even lawn you'd have a fit about this. And the carpets are all over the lawn, too. Given that he's sitting down he doesn't plan to move them for a while, meaning the lawn will sweat and suffer under those carpets. Think like a proud lawn curator, and don't do things like this.

Don't take a photo with a random kids stroller in the foreground. That's just weird.

The guy underneath the hatchback seems to be perving on a nearby neighbour, and enjoying it way too much. He's not actually doing anything, and is poorly positioned. He's holding what appears to be two chammy's yet is near the interior.

The guy on the right has a shirt that's looking hopelessly sloppy, and is wearing sandals. Is he just a stand-in? And seems to be strolling, not working.

All 3 should be wearing caps. That they have a uniform is great, though. That's the best part of the image.

The equipment should be neatly organised around the vehicle, not strewn out like a disaster zone.

The car has to feature more prominently in the shot. As does at least one of the worker's faces, whilst focused on working.

The logo is illegible. And tacky, and untrustworthy.

This is a business that comes to peoples houses. So you MUST provide your address for the purposes of building mutual trust.

etc etc etc...

try to think like a potential customer.

Comment: His question has nothing to do with the content of the photo, he is simply asking how to best apply his text and logo to the image.

Comment: He's simply asking how to better design marketing materials. FTFY

Comment: I agree with Confused. In any case the text (or a crop) could be done to hide some aspects he mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some thoughts that hopefully arn't too off topic.

In some cases **it may be better to leave out some of the information** on the image and place that in the message area on Facebook. One suggestion, have the only text on the image be "$40 OFF MOBILE CAR DETAILING.

Example

[image: text example]

You could add the phone number to the top right. You can get more creative and have the price be in some kind of water drop that is over the top part of the image or bottom right (to the right of the bottom guy).

Also, **If you were to boost the post** only 20% of your image can display text which is 5 squares in a grid. Also you should look up Facebook post dimensions as you will want to **design in a square format**.

**I also don't think you need your logo**. If people are coming to your page, they should already know it is you. They would only need to know if you were advertising to people who have not liked your page.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to create narrow white rectangle box spanning the entire image width and place the discount info in that box. Use simple fonts, no glow or anything just contrasting color for the font. The rest of the info goes just below that white box with contact info on the bottom left corner.

Comment: Hi Preston, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!