# How much text should I use for an ad image?

Tags: print-design, designers, marketing, advertising

I'm new at marketing and design and I could really use some tips.
What is the appropriate amount of text in an Ad image? I'm trying to figure out whether less text is better than more text.

**Here is an image I've edited and am considering publishing:**

[image]

**And this is the image I am currently running:**

[image]

I know the image is a bit stretched but please focus on the text, it is very complete, it includes the discounts info, our number and even our Logo.

However a number of text would not be needed. Our phone number for example isn't needed since the image is linked directly to our website with out contact information, our logo also isn't required since I am using facebook as an ad medium and our logo is our profile picture.

Is the first image better than the second because there is less text? or is the more text heavy image better?

**This is my base image for ads:**

[image]

Keep in mind these are for Facebook, and there is a 20% text rule that prohibits me from putting too much text in my images.

Comment: I might suggest leading the question with the last image. It seems to be the key image to the question. Also, the first line of your question is an introduction to yourself. Instead, the first line should probably be the most concise way you can think of to word your core question.

Comment: That couldn't hurt, I'll edit it now

Comment: I do think it is important for people to know that with Facebook, your text can only be 20% of the image which is 5 squares. That really limits the amount of text that can be added. I don't think text already apart of the photo counts towards the limit.

Comment: @AndrewH could you link something explaining what you just said? I've never heard this before.

Comment: @Ryan See Facebook [Ad Text Overlay Tool](https://www.facebook.com/ads/tools/text_overlay). You will have to log into Facebook to see this page. This goes for boosting a post. I haven't looked too much into the other ways of advertising on Facebook.

Comment: Andre, the 20% text rule is partly why I am asking this question, most the informative text can be in the description of the ad itself, but I'm wondering, much text is too little or too much?

Comment: @CesarDacoco I think you may want to re-edit your question to include this fact more prominently. I think you will get different answers based on this fact.

Comment: @AndrewH I will put it on there,  however, I dont want the 20% rule to be too focused upon, as I want to apply what suggestions are given in this post to other mediums of internet advertising, and not just facebook.

Comment: This is the second question you made about this add. You did not payed any atention to the sugestions people made on that one. You are making the same mistakes. I am sorry to say this, this image does not work as an add. It is not a matter of mathematics here. If the text is well written, and the image is good, Im sure you can extend the text. If the add has no design merit... That is just right.

Comment: This was a nice way to add emphasis on your text that @AndrewH did.  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/critique-how-should-i-place-format-an-informative-text-in-a-picture/55689#55689  Just use what should attract people to read the small text of the facebook post or click it, and don't overcharge your image (eg. $49 off + name of the offer).

Comment: @Rafael: This is a different question. He is trying to delve more deeply into the reasons and develop a deeper understanding as to why one design would be better than another.

Comment: @Rafael, its not that I didn't listen to you, its just that this is a different question. I have not applied the helpful tips I got on the first question you are talking about because as Chris said I am delving deeper into this before I edit the ad that is currently up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the contact info from the second image. But, keep it short and simple.

The text needs to be readable, like the first image.

A modern style really helps. The text should be readable even when it is a small image (i.e. a sidebar advert)

The photo really can't be stretched.

If you have a website, include it. I think it's written over the car logo, but I can't read that. A modern logo wouldn't hurt either.

So, to combine all these things, I've quickly thrown this together:

[image]

The text could be a little better, but I wanted to use an interesting yet readable font.

Comment: Better :) That other one was just hard to read :)

Answer (score 6):

An *excellent* rule of thumb is to *always* have a logo and contact information on *anything* that can be shared individually.

Realize people won't take a screenshot of your Facebook page and pass that around, but people *might* copy the image and pass that around.

The *only* reasons the first image is better are because A) the text is **actually readable** and B) the image is not distorted. However *content* is better in the second image.

Comment: One issue with putting the logo on Facebook advertising in particular is the "20%" rule that they have. You can't cover more than 20% of the image with text/logo.

Answer (score 3):

Logo and SOME contact information should be on all things. Now you don't need all of your contact info on everything.

- Brick and Mortar Store / Restaurant: Location is needed
- Online Reseller: Website is needed
- Service Provider like you: Phone number is needed

Now this is just fundamental and gets very open quickly. For example, does someone reserve their car detailing on your website? Then you need your website. Does the store also do online sales? And Phone Number is always a good idea because most will call first. Likewise as a Service Provider like you perhaps you don't need a physical address as much as a general area you serve to avoid getting calls from people too far for you.

Now the real issue in your text on the second image are two things:

1. It lacks visual clarity to be easily read as others have said, and how you have a question about. So I won't really say more on that.
2. The pricing issue. $40 off... begs the question off of what? And how do I get this? Do I have to print this image out? And why are larger vehicles getting a $55 off?? That makes no sense. Should be either the same dollar amount or the same percentage amount. Not to mention what's classified as a "Larger Vehicle?"

Basically, the key to text is the minimum amount needed to get your point across. And I think both images fail to do that currently. Logo should almost always be included as it helps with brand recognition.

You might want to really think about what the deal is, how does someone acquire the deal, and then put text in that specifically states those things.

For example:

> Mobile Car Detailing
>
> Call and mention this ad for 20% off your car detailing service!

*Note: This is about the same amount of text as you currently have, it's just more effective*

Followed by the phone number because you said to call.

Strong action verb for call-to-action like "Call" or "Come In" or "Visit" is almost always good to have and is missing from your current copy.

Answer (score 2):

Branding (logo) and contact info are very important to have on any ad piece. The readability of the second piece is very compromised, I would avoid using outline on text unless it is a header. The actual amount of text does not matter so long as the core message is being delivered concisely and accurately. IMHO $45 off doesn't tell me anything unless I know the base price the discount is being applied to. $45 off $50 is a great deal $45 off $300 is a markedly less appealing offer. It may make more sense to show this offer as a percentage or show the base price being reduced to add clarity.